# Getting SimpleSAML to work with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, simplesamlphp

I tried to add the directory that leads to the SimpleSAML files to the app.yaml, and it just isn't finding it for some reason.

Specifically, I added this snippet to the handlers section of the app.yaml file:

```
- url: /simplesaml/(.*)
  script: /var/simplesamlphp/www/\1
```

And, despite the fact that all of the files this app needs resides in /var/simplesamlphp/www/ directory, I am getting the following errors:

```
Warning: require(/Users/username/Projects/simplesamlphp/var/simplesamlphp/www): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php on line 106

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Users/username/Projects/simplesamlphp/var/simplesamlphp/www' (include_path='/Users/username/Projects/simplesamlphp:/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/php/sdk') in /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php on line 106
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem? If so, how did you solve said problem?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more info than that if you really expect help :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Perhaps I now have provided sufficient enough detail?

Comment: did you notice it uses following path `/Users/username/Projects/simplesamlphp/var/simplesamlphp/www`?

Comment: It does, but since app.yaml is in the "/Users/username/Projects/simplesamlphp" directory, shouldn't it be able to find the files the way I did it?